# Recommendations, thoughts, tips and tricks, or peanuts on moving from wordpress to django

Tags: django, wordpress

I've been using wordpress for a few years to run a couple of community based sites. one of them is a blog, while the other is more of an app, and I use wordpress for the admin feature only.

I'm thinking of moving to django as I'm familiar with python, I want to play with geodjango and I don't feel an urge or the need to do anything from scratch.

What are your thoughts on going from the wordpress blogging engine to the django framework in terms of programming, extensibility, scalability, speed, etc...

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django and wordpress cannot be compared, because, like it is said in django docs: "Django is a thing that you use to create things like wordpress".

If you would like to compare the speed:

Wordpress is really slow engine. One     of the slowest. Sometime it needs to     make 30 hits to database to show only    one page. 
      In django it completely depends    on how you white your app.       You     can make it slow, fast, or             whatever, depending on your skills       and functionality that you wish to       receive.

So, your question can't be answered, because you must decide whether you are whilling to make your new blog from scratch or not. If you are, then Django would be a great choice. If not, stay on the wordpress, or try a different engine.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is a **CMS**. Django is a **web development framework**. You cannot compare them in any reasonable way.

Everything that you get for free from Wordpress you will need to work for in Django, or at the very least install a pre-existing module for it.

The effects of scalability and performance will only depend on your implementation of the things you want to do in Django.

Comment: Wordpress is a CMS, but there is a full-featured framework underneath it.